# When to use weak_ptr instead of call by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have declared serialization class with the following methods, but did not implemented it yet:

```
    const std::string toJson(const Location &obj);

    const std::string toJson(std::weak_ptr<const Location> obj);

    const std::string toJson(std::shared_ptr<const Location> obj);
```

The job of the serialization class is, no surprise, to convert between one representation to another, e.g. from Json to the C++ class and vice-versa.

Now somewhere else in my code, I take unique ownership like this:

```
    std::unique_ptr<Location> uniqueLocation = getLocation();
```

Now my question is: The serialization does not need to take ownership of the unique_ptr. Which method should it call? The toJson using weak_ptr, or the toJson by reference?

Comment: If you don't intend to store the argument somewhere then I'd say `const &`.

Comment: You may find this Herb Sutter blog post relevant: https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Comment: You can't get a `unique_ptr` from a `weak_ptr` because a `weak_ptr` implies the object is already owned by one or more `shared_ptr`. An object can't be owned by both a `unique_ptr` and ` shared_ptr` at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a `std::shared_ptr` from a `std:::unique_ptr` (unless you `release()` its ownership first), and you can't create a `std::weak_ptr` from a `std::unique_ptr` at all, only from a `std::shared_ptr`.  So that leaves only one option:

`const std::string toJson(const Location &obj);`

Which makes sense, as you don't need or want `toJson()` to take/share ownership of the `Location` object, just to use it as-is.

To be honest, the other overloads don't really make much sense to have at all.  The caller should decide how it needs to obtain a reference to a `Location` object, and then pass the actual object to `toJson()` as needed, eg:

```
std::unique_ptr<Location> uniqueLocation = getLocation();
std::string s = toJson(*uniqueLocation);
```

But, if you want to keep the overloads, just have them delegate to the one overload that takes an object reference:

```cpp
const std::string toJson(const Location &obj)
{
    // do the actual work here...
}

const std::string toJson(std::weak_ptr<Location> obj)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Location> sp = obj.lock();
    return toJson(sp);
}

const std::string toJson(const std::shared_ptr<Location> &obj)
{
    std::string s;
    if (obj)
        s = toJson(*obj);
    return s;
}

const std::string toJson(const std::unique_ptr<Location> &obj)
{
    std::string s;
    if (obj)
        s = toJson(*obj);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`weak_ptr` is the companion to `shared_ptr`, and won't help you here.

You can use the first overload, or pass the `unique_ptr` itself by reference.

Even if you were using a `shared_ptr` rather than a `unique_ptr`, I'd advise the same. I've stored `weak_ptr`s in containers before (or captured them in lambdas), but if you're just passing into a function that needs to do some work, it seems like unnecessary overhead.

[Herb's opinion on the subject](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointers are about ownership.

Ownership is about lifetime.

```
const std::string toJson(const Location &obj);
```

This says "you will pass an `obj` which is a valid `Location`, and this function promises not to change it".

The return value -- `const std::string` -- is a toxic anti-pattern.  Don't do that.  Return `std::string`.

```
std::string toJson(std::weak_ptr<const Location> obj);
```

This states "I will take a possibly valid reference to an `obj`, which I will faithfully store somewhere.  At some unknown future point, I will check if that object still exists, and create a shared pointer to it.  Once you call this function, do not assume that the lifetime of the pointed to `obj` will end at any controlled spot; but usually I'll be polite, and not  hold onto a generated `shared_ptr` for more than a short bit".

```
std::string toJson(std::shared_ptr<const Location> obj);
```

This says "I want to participate in the shared management of the pointed to `obj`.  `obj` has and should have a complex lifetime which cannot be easily expressed through simple ownership.  I tried to use simpler ownership models, but they don't reflect the true essence of how long `obj` should survive, so I'm using reference counted pointers."

```
std::unique_ptr<Location> uniqueLocation = getLocation();
```

This says "I want to have controlled ownership of this object, which has never been in a complex ownership situation.  If I could, I'd be a value (or maybe an optional), but some issues block me from being a value.  So I'll be a unique pointer to a value."

> The serialization does not need to take ownership of the unique_ptr. Which method should it call? The toJson using weak_ptr, or the toJson by reference?

A function that converts things to Json probably just needs the object being converted to be valid the length of the call.

`toJson(const Location&)` is the one that means that.

Comment: Can you explain why not to return const std::string?

Comment: @benjist Sure; it does nothing particularly useful, and can inhibit move construction.  It is true that it blocks some bad use of `operator=`, but the loss of move-construction efficiency far outweights that.

Comment: I've created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570452/is-returning-a-const-stdstring-really-slower-than-non-const